# why is my tip calculator just returning $0.00?

Tags: python, edx

Im taking a course for learning python and this is the assignment they gave us

"""In the United States, it’s customary to leave a tip for your server after dining in a restaurant, typically an amount equal to 15% or more of your meal’s cost. Not to worry, though, we’ve written a tip calculator for you, below!

```
def main():

dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
tip = dollars * percent
print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")
def dollars_to_float(d):
# TODO
def percent_to_float(p):
# TODO
main()
```

Well, we’ve written most of a tip calculator for you. Unfortunately, we didn’t have time to implement two functions:

dollars_to_float, which should accept a str as input (formatted as $##.##, wherein each # is a decimal digit), remove the leading $, and return the amount as a float. For instance, given $50.00 as input, it should return 50.0.
percent_to_float, which should accept a str as input (formatted as ##%, wherein each # is a decimal digit), remove the trailing %, and return the percentage as a float. For instance, given 15% as input, it should return 0.15.
Assume that the user will input values in the expected formats."""

What you should end up getting is
How much was the meal? $50.00
What percentage would you like to tip? 15%
Leave $7.50
my problem is no matter what numbers i input, i end up getting "Leave $0.00" every single time. this is what i have written

```
def main():
dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
tip = dollars * percent
print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")

def dollars_to_float(d):
str.lstrip(d)
return float(d)
def percent_to_float(p):
str.rstrip(p)
return float(p)
main()
```

please help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure you understand how to post code so that it appears exactly as you actually have it, since indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: it looks fine to me

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  If I enter `50` and `0.2` in this program, I get the expected `$10` tip output.  However if I enter `$50.00` for the meal cost as you say you did, I get an error because of the dollar sign.

Comment: `str.lstrip(d)` does absolutely nothing. 1) You're supposed to use it like `d.lstrip()`, though your approach happens to work as well because reasons. 2) More importantly, `lstrip` et al *returns a new value*, it doesn't alter the value itself. Since you're not assigning that return value to anything, it just evaporates.

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah after the first set of coding i pasted what the assignment says which is that were supposed to make it so itll take $50.00 as an input and then the percent tip you want to leave as input as well and remove the $ and % , multiply the numbers to get the tip an then its supposed to print it.

Comment: Except you're _not_ removing the $ and %, because you're using `lstrip` and `rstrip` the wrong way.

Comment: @deceze got it!  im sure theres more i need to fix to get the right answer back but thank you for that i have fixed that part!

Comment: @JohnGordon right lol i was not aware of that unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
   dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
   percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
   tip = dollars * percent/100
   print(f"Leave $" , str(tip) )

def dollars_to_float(d):
   str.lstrip(d)
   return float(d)
def percent_to_float(p):
   str.rstrip(p)
   return float(p)
main()
```